# Filter array with multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having an array of objects and I would like to filter them on multiple conditions. Either if the `element.state === false` or the `element.url` contains a certain or multiple strings.

I tried to filter with a certain string however, I get an empty array back. Find below my example:

```js
const attr = ['Product 1', 'Product 2']

const res = []
for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
  res.push({
    attr: attr[i],
    url: 'category/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    attr: attr[i],
    url: 'costs/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    attr: attr[i],
    url: 'ownership/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    attr: attr[i],
    url: 'earnings/',
    state: false,
  }, {
    attr: attr[i],
    url: 'price/',
    state: false,
  })
}

/* console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
 */

function setState(obj, bool) {
  obj.state = bool
}

function getState(res) {
  return res.state
}

setState(res[1], true)

const para = 'category'
let currentState = res.filter((el, para) => {
  el.state === false && el.url === para
})

console.log(`Initial state: ${currentState.length}`)
while (currentState.length > 0) {
  currentState[0].state = true
  currentState = res.filter(el => el.state === false)
  console.log(`Set state to true for ${JSON.stringify(currentState[0])}`)
  console.log(currentState.length)
}

console.log('###################DONE#####################')


/*
 * ################
 * #Wanted Output for 'category' and 'ownership'
 * ################
 * {
 * attr: 'Product 1',
 * url: 'category/',
 * state: true
 * },
 * {
 * attr: 'Product 2',
 * url: 'category/',
 * state: true
 * },
 * {
 * attr: 'Product 1',
 * url: 'ownership/',
 * state: true
 * },
 * {
 * attr: 'Product 2',
 * url: 'ownership/',
 * state: true
 * }
 */
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: I see a couple of things with your `res.filter` statement. First, when you use a lambda function with curly braces, you have to explicitly return. So `(el,para)=> { return el.state === false /* etc... */ }`. Or get rid of the curly braces. Second, `el.url===para` will only be true for exact matches. If you wanted to do anything that contains "category," you'd want to do something like `/category/.test(el.url)` (case sensitive) or `/category/i.test(el.url)` (ignore case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several problems:

1. No `return` in `filter()`
2. The urls end in `/` so won't equal the `para` string that doesn't also end in `/`
3. Your `filter()` is using parameter name `para` also which shadows the `para` variable outside it

```js
const para = 'category'
let currentState = res.filter((el) => {
  return el.state === false && el.url.startsWith(para)
})

console.log(currentState)
```

```html
<script>
  const attr = ['Product 1', 'Product 2']
  const res = []
  for (let i = 0; i < attr.length; i++) {
    res.push({
      attr: attr[i],
      url: 'category/',
      state: false,
    }, {
      attr: attr[i],
      url: 'costs/',
      state: false,
    }, {
      attr: attr[i],
      url: 'ownership/',
      state: false,
    }, {
      attr: attr[i],
      url: 'earnings/',
      state: false,
    }, {
      attr: attr[i],
      url: 'price/',
      state: false,
    })
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're setting `para = 'category'` but the url is `'category/'` so the filtering returns nothing.

Also, in the function:

```
let currentState = res.filter((el) => { // <- removed the second element "para" because it will hold the index of el in res, which is not what you intended.
  el.state === false && el.url.indexOf(para) > -1; // check if it's a substring
})
```

The name `para` is misleading: the second parameter is the index of the element, and it's "hiding" the constant `para` that you declared outside.